# How can i make a entry into an array with an unknown size?

Tags: java, arrays

making a program that: 
-Asks user for test scores
-create array for scores 
-display lowest score 
-find and adjust mean score by dropping the lowest grade.

so far this is what i have:

```
public class AdjustingMarks 
{  
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        // Get numbers from the keyboard
        System.out.println("Please input your grade: ");
        int mark = scan.readInt();


    }
}
```

I am a bit confused as to how to make an array with an unknown size?

any help and guidance is appreciated
thank you.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `ArrayList`?

Comment: This is what an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html) is for.

Comment: Anyway, why so many people do the down vote? This is his/her first question post. I feel it is too strict.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CalcAverage
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int numScores;    // To hold the number of scores

      // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Get the number of test scores.
      System.out.print("How many test scores do you have? ");
      numScores = keyboard.nextInt();

      // Create an array to hold the test scores.
      double[] scores = new double[numScores];

      // Get the test scores and store them
      // in the scores array.
      for (int index = 0; index < numScores; index++)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter score #" +
                         (index + 1) + ": ");
         scores[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
      }

      // Create a Grader object, passing the
      // scores array as an argument to the
      // constructor.
      Grader myGrader = new Grader(scores);

      // Display the adjusted average.
      System.out.println("Your adjusted average is " +
                         myGrader.getAverage());

      // Display the lowest score.
      System.out.println("Your lowest test score was " +
                         myGrader.getLowestScore());
```

try this its a demo program of my group it should assist you in getting the idea of how to get the the info you need since it seems those who actually know what to do wont bother to help. Sorry I couldn't exactly answer your question.